# Why does onCreateView return the view that is inflated by it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I know onCreateView inflates the View of a fragment, but why does it also return the View?

What is the returned View ever used for?

The Fragment Manager of the activity the fragment is hosted by calls all fragment lifecycle methods, so does this mean the Fragment Manager uses the returned View from onCreateView? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the returned View ever used for?

It is used to allow the framework to display that portion of the UI. Otherwise, those widgets would be created, then ignored.

> so does this mean the Fragment Manager uses the returned View from onCreateView?

Yes.

> If so, how?

The fragment system calls `addView()` on the `ViewGroup` that will contain the view managed by the fragment.

Comment: does a call to addView() occur from a call to FragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit() ?

Comment: @qaz: Yes, or from a static fragment, or replace(), etc.